# Access database - Retrieve names of stored queries?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, database-schema

Is this possible programmatically? Getting the names of stored queries or checking if a query with a specific name exists?

Comment: WHy not SELECT * FROM <stored-query-name> LIMIT 1 and see if it errors out?

Comment: Sure why not! Db newb here :)

Comment: @Eugen Rieck You reckon that will work with MS Access?

Comment: @Remou why shouldn't it?

Comment: @Eugene Access does not have LIMIT 1 and you cannot select from action queries, so I cannot see how it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx) Method.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"connection_string");
connection.Open();
DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
         OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
           new object[] { null, null, null, "VIEW" });
foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows )
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
}
```

Comment: This will return only select queries, you will need OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures (PROCEDURE_NAME) for action queries (add, update, append etc). Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.procedures.aspx

Comment: I only have select stored queries in my db but thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `Procedures` table to get all stored procedures

`ProcedureName` field contains the name of the procedure

Comment: It's an access 97' database (yeah I know). Stored procedures have been available from 2000 and later. Sorry for not making that clear in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the undocumented but much-used `MSysObjects` table:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM [MSysObjects]
WHERE [Type] = 5
```

This will include any system queries created by Access for combo boxes, list boxes, and subforms.  They all start with a tilde, so you can exclude them like this:

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM [MSysObjects]
WHERE [Type] = 5
    AND [Name] NOT LIKE "~*"
```

Comment: You can often find that access to system tables is not allowed (permissions), and it is tedious in the extreme to find a solution.